# Recording video with flash and send videofile to server

Tags: flash, actionscript, webcam

Everyone knows that recording a video with the user's webcam is possible with flash in the browser - but all the solutions I found until now involve a rmtp server that accepts a stream from the flash app. Is there a way to use webcam recording without such an extra media server?

The usecase I want to implement is the following:

---

Show the user the output of his webcam on the screen. The user can hit a record button which will trigger the flash app to record 5 seconds of video material. The recorded video should be sent to the server as .flv file where it can be processed later.

---

Since the video will only be a few seconds long the amount of data is not a problem. But my actual question is: **Is this somehow technically possible to do in Flash?**

Comment: Yes that also what I expect the answer to be. But since I'm no flash developer I wanted to get evidence by an expert.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a jpg encoder (adobe core libs) to store a small series of jpgs as bytedata, zip it up (also adobe core libs) and send that to your server to be uncompressed and turned into an FLV. Warning, this could lead to quite large memory consumpsion if either the length is too long or the frame rate is high!

Comment: Thanks, thats a nice idea. But I think not implementable for real videos with framerates of ~25/sec.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected, I think the only way is to use a media server then. Red5 etc.

Comment: And it would be silent movies. In most video applications, you also want the audio.

Comment: Oh, now I see this is an old question, bumped by john's answer. Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third-party service in the cloud.  In that case you don't need to have a media server yourself.  You could probably use an online service like Nimbb to record and then move the FLV file to Amazon S3 or your own server.